# "Protected multilib versions:" during installation of wine on Fedora 21

Tags: fedora, yum, wine

I got an error when I try to install wine for fedora 21 with

```
sudo yum install wine
```

The error i'm reciving is

```
Error:  Multilib version problems found. This often means that the root
   cause is something else and multilib version checking is just
   pointing out that there is a problem. Eg.:

     1. You have an upgrade for libusbx which is missing some
        dependency that another package requires. Yum is trying to
        solve this by installing an older version of libusbx of the
        different architecture. If you exclude the bad architecture
        yum will tell you what the root cause is (which package
        requires what). You can try redoing the upgrade with
        --exclude libusbx.otherarch ... this should give you an error
        message showing the root cause of the problem.

     2. You have multiple architectures of libusbx installed, but
        yum can only see an upgrade for one of those architectures.
        If you don't want/need both architectures anymore then you
        can remove the one with the missing update and everything
        will work.

     3. You have duplicate versions of libusbx installed already.
        You can use "yum check" to get yum show these errors.

   ...you can also use --setopt=protected_multilib=false to remove
   this checking, however this is almost never the correct thing to
   do as something else is very likely to go wrong (often causing
   much more problems).

   Protected multilib versions: libusbx-1.0.19-2.fc21.i686 != libusbx-1.0.19-100.rc2.fc21.x86_64
```

How can I fix this? yum and rpm only finds the x86_64 version. I get this error

```
Package(s) libusbx.i686 available, but not installed.
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, I still had libusbx.x86_64 0:1.0.19-100.rc2.fc20 installed on my upgraded F21 system. I could resolve this by running

```
$ sudo yum downgrade libusbx.x86_64
```

You need to somehow bring the versions of the x86_64 and the i686 package in sync, and as 1.0.19-2 < 1.0.19-100 my assumption would be that downgrading the installed package should help.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was Chromium. Downgrading did not work. Had to remove it and disable repos to remove protection. Your profile should remain under `/home/user/.config/chromium` ,but if you need anything specific like bookmarks export them beforehand:

```
yum remove chromium  
-Change enabled=1 to enabled=0  
nano /etc/yum.repos.d/spot-chromium.repo  
nano /etc/yum.repos.d/google-chrome.repo   
yum install wine
```